# Script to relocate the menu-bar on dual monitors set-up

Tags: display, script, menu-bar

Is there a script that could be written to achieve this:
In System Preferences/Displays... is it possible to relocate the menu bar ...via a script?
My set-up is one monitor and a Cintiq. I either work only with the Cintiq, or I work with my 28" monitor several times a day. I always need to go to do this manually.
I really wish there was a script that can do this. I tried Automator, but it's not recording the action. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use a command line utility named [cscreen](http://www.pyehouse.com/cscreen/) to do that.  You can wrap it in a AppleSctipt script or in Automator.  You can download the cscreenIntel.dmg from the link provided. In a terminal use `cscreen -h` to output the internal help information.

I have a MBP and a Thunderbolt Display so in a Terminal I want to have `cscreen` list my displays

```
$ cscreen -l
DisplayID  Index     Depth     Width     Height  Refresh
5ac6fa7f       1        32      1440        900     0
 3247b0f       2        32      2560       1440     0
use -h to display all usage options
$
```

So to set the Thunderbolt Display to have the menu bar I run the following command:

`cscreen -s 2 -p`

I can then toggle it back using the same command as the **Index** shifts.

In AppleScript: `do shell script "/<path_to>/cscreen -s 2 -p"`

In Automator add **Run Shell Script** and add command: `/<path_to>/cscreen -s 2 -p`

Note:  This is a simple toggle if you only have two displays however if you have more then two you'll need to write some logic flow into the script.

You can also use, `cscreen -i <DisplayID> -p`, e.g. `cscreen -i 3247b0f -p` to code with the `DisplayID` which doesn't change.

This can also just be used in a Terminal as a singular command or incorporated into a shell script without using AppleScript and or Automator.

Answer (score 2):

For multi-monitor setups the tool I wrote, [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer), does this.

Configure your screens how you like, drag the "white bar" to your primary screen in the macOS system settings, and then execute `displayplacer list`. It will output the command to run to put your screens in their current configuration. The screen with `origin:(0,0)` is the main display with the "white bar". Run this terminal command through a script, Automator, BetterTouchTool, etc.

Example profile 1 puts the white bar on the menu bar on the left monitor.
`displayplacer "id:<leftScreenId> res:1920x1080 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0" "id:<rightScreenId> res:1920x1080 scaling:on origin:(1920,0) degree:0"`

Example profile 1 puts the white bar on the menu bar on the right monitor.
`displayplacer "id:<leftScreenId> res:1920x1080 scaling:on origin:(1920,0) degree:0" "id:<rightScreenId> res:1920x1080 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0"`

Also available via Homebrew `brew tap jakehilborn/jakehilborn && brew install displayplacer`

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach could be enabling "displays have separate spaces" in system prefs/Mission Control. That would enable menubars on both screens.

Comment: That is not an option in at least OS X 10.8 (and earlier, I'd imagine).